# RoR Sorcery GEM login doesnt want to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

so I have this project in RoR where I use sorcery gem for register and login,

my regiter is working good, I see the data inside database is added, but when I try to login using the same data it somehow doesnt recognize the data.

this is the function I am using from a tutorial for login.

```
  def logins
  user = login(params[:username], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
  if user
    redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid"
    render :new
  end
end
```

I am sure I entered the username and password correctly, but still it always shows email or password is invalid.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, because I'm out of ideas :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you post to "logins" action :email instead of :username option in params? Check your logs of request.

Comment: I got this error in error log Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qBo1vY9oLwV2w3kBlj8Lb/FO4jvkME7rtluqVl7AiJE=", "user"=>{"username"=>"drakelv", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>""}

  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username = NULL) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 287ms

Comment: Ok.You must write like this: user = login(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password], params[:user][:remember_me])

Answer (score 0):

Since your param is like this: `"user"=>{"username"=>"drakelv", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}`, you should call `user = login(params['user']['username] ... )` instead of `user = login(params[:username], params[:password], params[:remember_me])`. Maybe `login(params['user'])` will work also.